# Using an object outside of its declaration file (C++)

Tags: c++, class, object, scope, static

(it is be possible that this question has been asked very often already and i am sorry about this repost, but anything i found just didnt help me, since i am relatively a beginner at c++)

so here is an example to show my problem

i have the class monster

```
class Monster{
public:
Monster();

void attack();

private:
int _health;
int _damage;
};
```

and i have the class Level

```
class Level{
Level();
};
```

i have created the object "snake" from the class Monster in my "main.cpp"

```
#include "Monster.h"

int main(){

Monster snake;

}
```

now what do i do if i want to use "snake" in my "Level" class? if i want to do "snake.attack();" inside of "Level.cpp" for example?

If i declare it again in "Level.cpp" it will be a seperate object with its own attributes wont it?

i have always been making the member functions of my classes static until now, so i could do "Monster::attack();" anywhere in my program but with this tachnique i cant have multiple objects doing different things depending on their attributes (snake1, snake2, bat1, etc...)

thanks for the help in advance! 
(and sorry for the possibly reoccuring question)

Comment: Why not buy a book on C++ and read it? Otherwise this will be a time consuming exercise of asking questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming those snips are your .h files.

Your level.cpp should something like this:

```
#include "level.h"   // its own header
#include "monster.h" // header with Monster::attack() declaration

Level::DoAttack(Monster& monster) { // using snake as parameter.
  health = health - monster.attack(); // monster hits us, subtract health.
}
```

monster.h would be

```
class Monster{
public:
  Monster();

  void attack();

private:
  int _health;
  int _damage;
};
```

and monster.cpp

```
Monster::attack() {
  // code to calculate the attack
}
```

Comment: but the function does not recongnize the object "monster" unless it was created within its file. even though i included "Monster.h"

Comment: As long as Monster is declared in the header it should be ok, the Monster::attack() function needs to be implemented in the monster.cpp file.

Comment: Thanks! that was it. i though i already tried that but maybe i did something else wrong that time. is it usual to declare objects in the headerfiles? or is there any reason not to?

Answer (score 0):

I could not completely understand your questions.But from what I understood.I think you want to access a Monster object instantiated in main() to be used inside level.So,here is what you can do.Add a constructor inside the level class which takes a monster object as an argument.Then instantiate a level object and pass the monster object in it.Like this,
Level l=new Level(snake);

Comment: i tried to make it as simple and straight forward as i could but maybe i fell short on details.

all i want to do is create an object (Monster snake) from the class "Monster" inside of my main.cpp. but afterwards i want to be able to use that exact object inside of a different file ( for example "Level.cpp") to do something like snake.attack(); 
but whenever i do this, the compiler doesnt recognize the identifier "snake" because it was declared in a completely different file.i basically want global objects

Comment: Did you try my solution?In that solution,a copy of monster class object will be received by the level class.If you want the same object and not the copy,pass it by reference.It can be done like,Level(Monster &m) as the constructor inside level class.

Comment: i honestly did not because the solutions seemed so far from what i expected. it sounds stupid but i thought my problem was so simple that i did not think your solution would be the right one.
your solution would work but it would make it very complicated to implement it into my existing code. i now know that i simply have to declare my objects in the headerfiles right after the class and they will be included in every file i include the headerfile in (i hope that doesnt declare a new object every time.. then i might use your method) 
thanks for the solution anyways!

Comment: What is important is that the problem is solved.It hardly matters whose answer solved it.

Answer (score 0):

By *declaring* a class you're not creating any objects. You normally declare a class by including the corresponding header file.

So, in `Level.h` you'd `#include <Monster.h>`, then you can reference it inside `Level`.

But seriously, you can't write much C++ code without understanding the basic things such as declaration vs. definition, header files (.h), classes vs. objects, pointers and references, etc. It would be best to invest in a book or at least to read some tutorials online.

Comment: but i declare objects right? because thats what i ment. i know i have to include the headerfile of the class i want to access but even when i did, i could not use an object in that file. even when i declared/created an object in main and then wanted to use the same object in its own corresponding .cpp file, it would not work because it was undefined

Comment: You declare a *class*. Then you instantiate a class to get an *object*. `Monster snake;` instantiates an object `snake` of type `Monster`. Until then, the `class Monster` is declared (i.e. known to the compiler), but no object of it exists.

Comment: but after i have gotten the object and it is there, it has its attributes etc, how do i use it from other files? i have included the corresponding .h file but i cannot use my object from any other file but the one it was created in. arent there global objects or something like that? 
i know i am a rookie and i try to learn as much as i can by reading on the internet, but i never found anything about this.

Comment: You can pass a pointer or a reference to it to other objects. `Monster*` declares a pointer to an object of type Monster, `Monster&` - a reference.